# Redis rdb file keeps growing in size

Tags: redis

My redis rdb file keeps growing and growing in size until the db becomes inoperational and connections are refused. I realise this is to do with some config setting - I'm using the default config file.

Is there any way I can prevent this ? I'm not to concerned about constant backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is obviously in the redis.conf,

```
#   Note: you can disable saving at all commenting all the "save" lines.
#
#   It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
#   points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
#   like in the following example:
#
#   save ""

save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

the text above is in redis.conf,   if u don't want to save the rdb file,  comment the three line begin with save, such as

```
#   Note: you can disable saving at all commenting all the "save" lines.
#
#   It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
#   points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
#   like in the following example:
#
#   save ""

# save 900 1
# save 300 10
# save 60 10000
```