# Redis updates .rdb file every minute on slave

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, replication

I have Amazon ElastiCache redis instance and EC2 instance with slave of ElastiCache. 
Slave instance used to create AOF files for backups.

On slave I have config of "save":

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> config get save
1) "save"
2) ""
```

Because I dont want rdb-snapshotting, I want to use only AOF persistence.

As config says redis should not make .rdb snapshot at all if "save" is empty string.

But in redis data directory of slave I have dump.rdb:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis   redis   299349931 Dec 14 09:21 appendonly.aof
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis   redis   195499337 Dec 14 09:22 dump.rdb
```

And dump.rdb updates every minute!

I see that redis dumps .rdb first in temp file, then replaces old .rdb file.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis   redis           0 Dec 14 09:24 temp-1387013084.24100.rdb
```

Please help me, how to keep only AOF persistence on slave, without .rdb file?

Comment: You can see this post,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430786/redis-rdb-file-keeps-growing-in-size/20449783#20449783

Comment: Slave param "save" is set to "". I think I found answer to my question: Amazon ElastiCache Redis version is 2.6. It doesn't supports partial replication and Redis slave always downloads full database from master as RDB file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slave will dump an RDB file every time that it looses the replication connection or replication is restarted (for example: https://redislabs.com/blog/the-endless-redis-replication-loop-what-why-and-how-to-solve-it/).

Comment: the link is dead.